# How do you simplify $¬ ((¬Q \land ¬P) \lor ¬P)$

Tags: logic

Please help. I've missed some lectures, and now I'm stuck (my fault!). The lectures notes don't explain elaborately, and I can't find good tutorials online. I've somehow managed to arrive at $(Q \lor P) \land P$. If this is correct, can this be simplified further? Thanks heaps.

Comment: What kind of rules you can use $?$

Answer (score 1):

Replacing $\lor$ by $+$ and $\land$ by $\cdot$ makes it easy to see the further possible simplification
$$(Q+P)\cdot P = Q\cdot P+P = (Q+1)\cdot P = P$$

$P\cdot P = P\land P = P$ because "$\land$" of two inputs is true when "both" its inputs are true. Saying both $P, P$ are true is same as saying $P$ is true.

$Q+1=1$ because "$\lor$" of two inputs is true when "at least" one input is true. Since one input is already true, $Q+1=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can still be simplified further, the idea is using Commutative law and Absorption law,
I suppose you need to simplify this with [Logical equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence), and the proof is simple:
$$¬((¬Q \land ¬P) \lor ¬P)\tag*{Start from}$$
$$\neg(¬Q \land ¬P)\land P\tag*{De Morgan's law}$$
$$(Q\lor P)\land P\tag*{De Morgan's law}$$
$$P\land(P\lor Q)\tag*{ Commutative law$\times2$}$$
$$P\tag*{Absorption law}$$

Therefore this simplified the expression.

Answer (score 1):

Using de Morgan's laws and the double negation law:

$$\neg ((\neg Q \land \neg P) \lor \neg P) \equiv \neg (\neg Q \land \neg P) \land \neg \neg P$$
$$\equiv \neg (\neg Q \land \neg P) \land P$$
$$\equiv  (\neg \neg Q \lor \neg \neg P)\land P$$
$$\equiv (Q \lor P)\land P$$

Next, you could use the absorption law and commutative law to conclude that

$$ (Q \lor P)\land P \equiv P \land (Q \lor P) \equiv P \land (P \lor Q) \equiv P$$

If you haven't proved the absorption law in class then you could directly prove the result through the same strategy in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3413261/absorption-law-proof) and [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Absorption_Laws_(Boolean_Algebras)).