# Prove ((p→q)∧q) and q are equivalent using logic laws

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

So far I have

((p→q)∧q)
≡ ((~p∨q)∧q)
≡ (~p∧q)∨(q∧q) $\; \; \; \; \;$(Distributive law)

≡ (~p∧q)∨q

But then I got stuck. And I'm not sure if what I've got so far is correct. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3413261/absorption-law-proof): apply [Distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Rule_of_replacement) to the RHS in the form: $(\lnot p∨q) ∧ (q ∨ \bot)$ to get: $q \lor (\lnot p \land \bot)$

Answer (score 0):

Use the *Absorption laws*
$$a \land (a \lor b) \equiv a$$
$$a \lor (a \land b) \equiv a$$
We can easily verify this.

Comment: See here for more info https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_law

Comment: Yes, but maybe the issue is how to prove it... If we rely on truth table, the original problem is easily solved.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA the OP has to add more context. In standard courses, we are told to verify De Morgan's law, Absorption law, Double Negation law, Idempotent etc then use them freely.

Comment: I wonder if there is another law that I can use to solve this problem. We have not yet covered Absorption laws but we were still assigned this problem.

Comment: @Biki maybe there is a method. but next step is surely not Distributive law since that loops between $(\neg p \lor q) \land q$ and $(\neg p \land q) \lor q$

Comment: i agree with @MauroALLEGRANZA. you have not proven anything by simply stating it is so via a derived rule

Answer (score 0):

**I offer a proof of the syntactic equivalence $(p \to q) \wedge q \dashv \vdash q$ via natural deduction using only conditional proof and intro/elimination rules for conjunction**:

$(p \to q) \wedge q \vdash q$

$
\begin{array}{11111}
\{1\} & 1. & (p \to q) \wedge q & \text{premise} \\
\{1\} & 2. & q& \text{1 Conjunction Elimination} & \square\\
\end{array}
$

$ q \vdash (p \to q) \wedge q$

$
\begin{array}{11111}
\{1\} & 1. & q & \text{premise} \\
\{2\} & 2. & p & \text{Assumption for Conditional Proof} \\
\{1,2\} & 3. & p \wedge q & \text{1,2 Conjunction Introduction} \\
\{1,2\} & 4. & q& \text{3 Conjunction Elimination} \\
\{1\} & 5. & p \to q & \text{2,4 Conditional Proof} \\
\{1\} & 6. & (p \to q) \wedge q& \text{1,5 Conjunction Introduction} & \square \\
\end{array}
$